# Java WatchService and Firefox strange behavior

Tags: java, firefox, watchservice

I use the sample from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html to watch user downloads folder in order to react when a specific file type is downloaded by user. The code listens only for `ENTRY_CREATE` events and I have discovered a strange behavior of Firefox: the code received `ENTRY_CREATE` event twice. I have modified the code to listen to all type of file events:

```
for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
  WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();
  WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
  Path filename = ev.context();
  Path filePath = downloadsFolder.resolve(filename);
  
  System.out.println(kind + ": " + filePath + ": " + filePath.toFile().length());
}
```

and for a file 'sample.pdf' downloaded via Firefox the log was:

```
ENTRY_CREATE: C:\Users\<user.home>\Downloads\sample.pdf: 458971
ENTRY_DELETE: C:\Users\<user.home>\Downloads\sample.pdf: 458971
ENTRY_CREATE: C:\Users\<user.home>\Downloads\sample.pdf: 458971
ENTRY_MODIFY: C:\Users\<user.home>\Downloads\sample.pdf: 458971
```

Is this a Firefox bug? What's the point of creating, deleting and than creating once again the same file?

Comment: I think this is because Firefox first creates an empty file with the name of the file being downloaded together with a `.part` file (which holds the downloaded content). After the download is completed, the empty file is deleted and the `.part` file is renamed to the original file name.

Comment: But how can this "empty file" have size 458971? Is it filled with 0s (for example)?